# TypeScript ESLint Parser

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

> As per doc says, [tsc parser](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/parser#parseroptionsproject) that some rules need tsconfig
> information to require types like:
>
> "airbnb-typescript","plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
> rules.

But as much as i play with the tsconfig, im not seeing any difference
in that rules. Where exactly these rules use the tsconfig and what
exactly do they read from it?  Thank you.

**eslint**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
  },

  extends: [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ["/*.*"],
};
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true, 
    // "alwaysStrict": true,
    // "esModuleInterop": false, 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true, 
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "ES2015"], 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "module": "es6", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5", 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outDir": "./typescriptDist"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["app/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",` line is what adds in rules that use type information. Documentation was since added to typescript-eslint.io after this question was asked:

- https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started: Explains the non-type-checking aspects
- https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting: Explains linting with type information
- https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs: Explains what each of those configs do

  - That includes `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked'`, which is what the latest versions of typescript-eslint renamed `'.../recommended-type-checked'` to
  - The linked [`recommended-type-checked.ts`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/066ccf75d126df22a1792d3de3d1e3dd28904db1/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended-type-checked.ts) includes the exact list of type-checked rules enabled in the config

tl;dr: "Type checked" rules use TypeScript's type APIs to ask for information on *types* of code. That kind of info requires a TSConfig (most commonly, `tsconfig.json`) and reading across potentially many files in your codebase (e.g. to know what type an imported value is). That makes these rules slower
but more powerful than traditional linting rules.

For example, [`@typescript-eslint/await-thenable`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/await-thenable) flags any `await` in front of something that's not a "Thenable" (most commonly, a `Promise`). Unnecessary `await`s can be a sign of dead code. But knowing whether an awaited value is a Thenable or not often requires type information.